# New close options duplicate migration to Super User

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I notice with the recent changes to the close options, superuser.com is still listed under the migration options, but there's also a more direct suggestion: `It's about general computing hardware and software. The post author may be able to get help on Super User.`

Is this by design? If so, how should we decide whether to choose this option, or `This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network -> belongs on superuser.com`?

Comment: It's best to recommend a site only when you're familiar with its rules and question standards. Voting as off-topic is a *lot* safer than voting to migrate. Note that *both* the old and the new General Computing reason include the suggestion that Super User *may* be the appropriate site.

Comment: No; if anything, I am asking why we don't have *fewer* options. In the past I've asked on the meta about other options for flagging migration, and the whole thing seems so frustrating that I'd rather forget that there was ever such a thing as migration. :/

Comment: The close reason doesn't mean "should be migrated to superuser" but rather "superuser *may* be a better option". It's not a migration path but an actual close reason because the question, as it stands, is simply off-topic. But it's asking for something that is more in the domain of superuser. The asker can then re-ask a (potentially updated) question over there. But not all hardware questions are superuser questions - "how do I unplug my vacuum cleaner from the power outlet" does not belong there "how do I configure my OS to play a jingle when I move my cursor" does.

Answer (score 11):

This is not new... The very first option under the "off topic" category has pretty much always been for questions related to general computing hardware and software.

Old text:

> Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

New text:

> **It's about general computing hardware and software.** The post author may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

You should choose to migrate in cases where you actually think the question is well-asked and would be well-received on Super User (or any other site, for that matter). In all other cases, you should choose to simply close as off-topic. The close reason you cite is for questions that you don't think deserve to be migrated anywhere. (Hint: this is *most* of them.)

Comment: Trying to figure out the requirements of other SE sites for "well-asked" is rather frustrating IMX. But it's usually clear that someone has "an X question, not a programming question" and that there exists an X.SE.

Comment: It isn't nearly as hard as people make it. I'll grant that sites like Code Review and Hardware Recommendations have some tricky requirements, but Super User and Server Fault are not at all complicated. What gets people into trouble is saying, oh, this looks like it's about general computing, so I should migrate it... When really, it's not even a question at all, and it's barely intelligible, so you obviously should not migrate it anywhere. The rule is, don't migrate crap. If you wouldn't want it on your site, you shouldn't dump it on anyone else's site.

Comment: I would replace *most* with *the overwhelming majority*.